# Powershell: how to detect non-last exit code in pipe

Tags: powershell

Next powershell script

> cmd /c "@exit 42" | cmd /c "@exit 0"
>
> echo $LASTEXITCODE

output 0 as result of second execution. Is it possible read somehow exit code of first command (42)?

Bash afaik has PIPESTATUS array for these purposes. But I can't find analogue for powershell...

Comment: I think I have a similar problem and I think I ended up piping the result to a temporary file first, and then read the temporary file, follow by deleting it. Maybe there is a better way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you test :

```
$(& cmd /c "@exit 43"; $a=$lastexitcode) | cmd /c "echo %%1 & @exit 0"
$a
$LASTEXITCODE
```